# Wie sagt man "to babyproof" zB ein Zimmer/Haus auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation

Gibt es überhaupt eine ähnliche Übersetzung? 
Ich weiß, man könnte einfach sagen, dass man das Haus sicherer fürs Baby gemacht hat aber ich wollte wissen, ob es ein anderer Begriff gäbe.

Comment: Geht es darum, daß das Kleinkind sicher ist, oder darum, daß es das Zimmer nicht zerlegt?

Comment: Dass das Kleinkind sicher ist und nicht von irgendetwas im Zimmer verletzt sein kann.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eine Möglichkeit, das auszudrücken ist:

> Ein Zimmer babysicher machen.

Andere Varianten wären:

> Ein Zimmer kindersicher machen.
>   Ein Zimmer kleinkindersicher machen.
>   Ein Zimmer kleinkindsicher machen.

Comment: kleinkindsicher wäre auch noch eine Alternative, zumindest im normalen Sprachgebrauch.

Comment: *Das Zimmer zwergerlfest machen* wäre auch noch eine Möglichkeit, jedenfalls im landschaftlichen Gebrauch.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Allerdings ist das wohl auch nur in Bayern gebräuchlich.